# VLAN trunk (noob question)

Tags: vlan

I've been reading about a VLANS for a while, couple of times. And I believe I just can't get a catch at something.. Or maybe missunderstand some part, because I can't get it working the way I want.

I would really appreciate some help, cause I believe the best way to learn things is by trying, right?

So I have been setting up this home LAB for playing around. The setup is below:

Router TP-LINK WDR3600 with dd-wrt.
The interfaces on the router:

```
ath0 - Wi-Fi interface, running in client mode to connect to gateway
ath0.1 - AP mode. SSID#1 192.168.0.0/24 network
ath0.2 - AP mode. SSID#2 10.100.10.0/24 network
ath1 - AP mode used to bridge another AP to 192.168.0.0/24
vlan1 - ethernet ports (dd-wrt default)
vlan2 - WAN port (dd-wrt default).
vlan30 - the VLAN created by me in order to seperate two ports from vlan2.
br0 - containing ath0, ath0.1, ath1, vlan1, vlan2
br1 - containing ath0.2, vlan30
```

DHCP configuration:

```
br0 - 192.168.0.0 network
br1 - 10.100.10.0 network
```

VLAN port assignment on the router:

```
LAN 1:
    vid: 1
    ports: 0t 3 4 5 
VLAN 2:
    vid: 2
    ports: 0t 1 
VLAN 30:
    vid: 30
    ports: 0t 2
```

Explanation: 0 is CPU, 1 is WAN, 2-5 are the other ethernet ports on the router.

So at first my goal was to simply make a separate subnet, so I created `SSID#2 on ath0.2.` I wanted to add my Hyper-V server (connected on the ethernet port) to that subnet, so I created additional vlan30 and assigned `port 2  to VLAN30`. 
Then I created `br1(ath0.2(SSID#), vlan30)` so that I could reach that Hyper-V server from SSID#2. Everything is working as expected.
Great it was finally working!

Now the tricky part comes in. I have another cable attached to the router and the smart switch at the end of it. I have some devices connected there.

I wanted to add some of these devices to the VLAN1 and some to the VLAN30.
So I changed my router VLAN port membership to as follows:

```
LAN 1:
    vid: 1
    ports: 0t 3 4 5 
VLAN 2:
    vid: 2
    ports: 0t 1 
VLAN 30:
    vid: 30
    ports: 0t 2 3t
```

(An uplink to a switch is port 3)

And changed the port membership of the switch to:

```
VLAN 1:
    vid: 1
    ports: 1u x 3u 4u 5u 6u 7u 8u 
VLAN 30:
    vid: 30
    ports: 1t 2u x  x  x  x  x  x
```

(the uplink to a router is on port 1)

**This is what I want to achieve:**

*So I was hoping, that when I plug a device to port 2 on the switch, it would get an IP from 10.100.10.0, when I plug it to any other port it would get an IP from 192.168.0.0.*

I can get an IP from 192.168.0.0 but not from the 10.100.10.0. I believe I am surely missing something about t/u and trunk.

As I understood, to have trunk port you can use default switches vlan with untaged port. I want it, so that I could setup more vlans using single cable from router to switch. At least I think that I need to do this.

Apologies if the question seems too long, just wanted to give all the information I could.

**Edit#1:**

I have confirmed that I successfully setup VLAN30 on the first side (the router). Everything was working.

On the other end lays a NETGEAR switch. 
On the netgear docs, I read that a way to setup trunk is basically leaving the port untagged to the default VLAN on the switch.

Now, I basically want to ask this am I correct thinking that, with the following setup:

```
SWITCH 1:
VLAN1: 3u 4u 5u
VLAN30: 2u 3t

SWITCH2
VLAN1: 1u 3u 4u 5u 6u 7u 8u (port1 should become trunk according to NETGEAR docs)
VLAN30: 1t 2u
```

I would be able to reach VLAN30 on SWICTH2 port2? And VLAN1 on ports 3,4,5,6,7,8?

Comment: Just for your information, I am a professional networking guy and I failed badly at setting up a Netgear switch for VLANs. Packets were leaking from one VLAN to another, and it was possible to configure a port as being untagged in several VLANs at the same time. I would not recommend relying on Netgear behavior to understand VLANs...

Comment: Unfortunately questions about home networking and/or consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You should try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: If you read more carefully, you would see that the edited version of question is about VLAN tagging itself. Ignoring the use case, both consumer or enterprise grade equipment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost always the case that you've missed a connection required for the basic services - folks forget that a VLAN really is a separate network, and needs every service either directly set up on it (simplest) or via a "helper" route.

I'm not clear that you ever got VLAN30 set up and working correctly in the first switch, which you should certainly do before worrying about getting it working on another switch. Also check to see if a manually set address in the VLAN30 range works on the port that is VLAN30 before you get too wound up about the DHCP working - step by step verification is key when figuring out WHERE the holes in a VLAN setup are.

Without knowing the particular terminology of your switch/router I'm wondering if you needed to define something like "ath0.30" to access/provide services to the tagged VLAN30. But I'm also finding your question a bit muddy to wade through exactly what you have done.

Tagged, untagged and trunk are related in that VLANS on a trunk are tagged; depending on the exact era and VLAN setup of the switch that works in various ways.

- I have some switches that only have "trunk" and "device" as options -
  everyting on a "trunk" port is tagged, and a trunk port can be a
  member of several VLANs. Nothing on a Device port is tagged, and it
  can only be a member of one VLAN. That is an older switch model.
- More recent ones have "tagged" and "untagged" and can have both
  tagged and untagged traffic on the same port, and each port has an
  assigned PVID - the VLAN to which untagged incoming traffic is
  assigned. Typically tagged traffic matching the PVID is untagged as it leaves the port, though that may be a setting that can be changed, depending on the switch.

Comment: I have edited the question